# How to Install ibPy on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, installation, ibpy

I am quite a rooky in Python but i aim to build trading algos using Python and interactive broker.
I have downloaded ibPy on my Mac. I now have a folder in my "download" directory that I do not know what to do with :
- should I drag it somewhere ? Where ?
- how to actually set up ibPy on my computer.

Please feel free to be as specific as possible since I really do not get how that works. I have been using pip3 randonly (with random success previously) but it does not work here.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the IbPy package but if you want to install it using the pip install manager you just need to execute:

```
$ pip install IbPy
```

This command will install the latest version of this package in [the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

If you want to use the downloaded one it will be probably packaged with [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html). Then you'll have to install it with:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

If the file you downloaded is compressed in a *file.tar.gz* you will have to uncompress first:

```
$ tar xzf file.tar.gz
$ cd file
$ python setup.py install
```

Replace *file* with the name of your downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this. If you want to load IbPy on a Mac OS you have to load the IbPy2 package

```
$ pip install IbPy2
```

or

```
$ pip3 install IbPy2
```

depending on your python version.

See more info:

https://github.com/blampe/IbPy